# How to get second row in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next table:

```
COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE     PK    NULLABLE
inc_id      bigint        YES   NO
dt_cr       timestamp     NO    NO
email       varchar(255)  NO    YES
```

`email` column is not unique, so I should use `GROUP BY email`.

**Question**:
How can I get from this table minimal date, next row after minimal date and email related to this dates?

I read about `first_value` and `nth_value` functions, code listed below, but seems like it doesn't work correct.

```
SELECT J1.email, J2.first_date, J2.second_date 
FROM (
    SELECT email 
    FROM orders 
    GROUP BY email) J1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT email, 
        first_value(dt_cr) over (order by dt_cr ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) first_date, 
        NTH_VALUE(dt_cr, 2) over (order by dt_cr ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) second_date 
    FROM orders) J2  
ON (J1.email=J2.email);
```

Any ideas?

--edited
maybe it can be done with `rank()` function..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query uses `WITH` construction that works similar to sub-queries. Investigate this query with `EXPLAIN` before use in production because it may be slow on big tables:

```
WITH orders AS (
    SELECT 
          email
        , first_value(dt_cr) OVER wnd1 AS min_date
        , nth_value(dt_cr, 2) OVER wnd1 AS second_date 
    FROM orders
    WINDOW wnd1 AS ( PARTITION BY email ORDER BY email, dt_cr)
)
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM orders
WHERE second_date IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: when i execute your query I'm getting : `Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "wnd1";`

Comment: also I'm execute all queries in aws redshift, and this query doesn't work here.. it also need frame clause

Comment: Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2. You may need to move window definition in `SELECT` clause: first_value(dt_cr) OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY email, dt_cr ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) . There is a description and example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_AVG.html

Comment: yes, I'll fix it, all working for now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Try with `row_number` function.

Within whole table:

```
select * 
from(select *, row_number() over(order by dt_cr) rn from tableName)t 
where rn <= 2
```

Or within `email`:

```
select * 
from(select *, row_number() over(partition by email order by dt_cr) rn from tableName)t 
where rn <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have actually tried a different approach

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (email) o1.email, o1.dt_cr AS first_date, o2.dt_cr AS seconf_date 
FROM orders o1
INNER JOIN orders o2 ON o1.email = o2.email AND o1.inc_id != o2.inc_id
ORDER BY o1.email, o1.dt_cr ASC
```

Not sure if this is what you needed, a sample data would be helpful. Anyway I have created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/49213/2) for my result.